# python beatifull soup, find only exact class matches

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, webdriver

hello so i have this little script

```
html = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")
parse = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
selector = Selector(text=html)
divs = selector.css('.panel .panel-heading a::attr(href)').getall()
```

and it works fine but i if div has

```
<div class="panel grey">
```

i dont want this to match, only exact matches when div has one div
match only this

```
<div class="panel">
```

i tried using decompsoe() function but didnt worked in my case, what is the best solution i have my script done this is the only issue

so in short, find children of div only if div has one class

Comment: I think the problem is that "panel gray" is probably a child of "panel"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To strictly match `div` with `class` **equals** to `panel` value, not just some element that **contains** `panel` class attribute you can write that explicitly.
Instead of

```
divs = selector.css('.panel .panel-heading a::attr(href)').getall()
```

try using

```
divs = selector.css('div[class="panel"] .panel-heading a::attr(href)').getall()
```